# Node.js thread pool vs worker_thread

Tags: node.js, multithreading, threadpool, worker-thread

thread pool size can be determined with *UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE*.
*Worker_thread* can create threads dynamically in runtime. 
Is this a only difference between thread pool and worker thread? 
Recently, I'm so curious about node.js! Can anyone tell me differences between thread pool and worker thread plz...?

Also, I heard when worker_threads are created they also have v8 and eventloop their own.
 Then, would it be more efficient to define thread pool size using *UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE*?

Comment: hi, perhaps might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404784/how-nodejss-internal-threadpool-works-exactly

Comment: thanks! I've checked the link, but still I couldn't find the differnce between thread pool and worker_thread..

Answer (score 0):

From https://nodejs.org/en/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop:

> **What code runs on the Worker Pool?**
>
> The Worker Pool of Node.js is
> implemented in libuv (docs), which exposes a general task submission
> API.
>
> Node.js uses the Worker Pool to handle "expensive" tasks. This
> includes I/O for which an operating system does not provide a
> non-blocking version, as well as particularly CPU-intensive tasks.
>
> ...
>
> In many Node.js applications, these APIs are the only sources of tasks for the Worker Pool. Applications and modules that use a C++ add-on can submit other tasks to the Worker Pool.

The Node.JS thread pool is a collection of "true" threads that share memory with each other and perform tasks in parallel with the main thread.  Worker threads, on the other hand, aren't "true" operating system threads in this sense - they are actually closer to a [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) because creating a Worker thread creates an entirely new Node.JS process that doesn't share any memory with the main thread. This is also why you can have arbitrarily many threads in the thread pool without a huge impact to memory, but can't do the same with worker threads. The main difference between worker threads and child processes is that worker threads implement an event-based messaging system between the parent thread and the child thread which allows for a much more efficient and convenient method of communication than what is available with child processes.